# Custom board causing strange oscillations on SPI lines

Tags: spi, transmission

**Question**

What could be causing the following corruption on my SPI lines?
[image: Odd SPI oscillations]

**Background**

I have designed a daughter board which is connected to a Bajie Development board ([first listing on this page](http://www.chinaqmtech.com/xilinx_zynq_soc)). The Bajie board utilizes a Xilinx XC70Z010 SoC. On the daughterboard, I am attempting to control a Texas Instruments LMX2572 frequency synthesizer over SPI. But the analog board has injected a pattern that is corrupting SPI transmission (See above image.) Upon closer inspection, the comb pattern reveals itself as a series of small packets (see image below.)
[image: Strange packets]

My first inclination is that this is the result of clock interference. I have a 100 MHz clock connected close to the LMX2572 on the analog board. However, these packets are not at 100 MHz but are at a much lower frequency (6.66 MHz).

My question for the forum is this. What common board design mistakes may have caused this pattern to emerge?

There is a similar pattern on SPI lines of the SoC side of the transmission.

[image: SoC corruption]

Could the corruptions on the analog side be related to the SoC side? This was my thought but both corrupted patterns emerge even when the two boards are disconnected. And the SoC side corruptions appear despite the code being stopped at a breakpoint.

Comment: First mistake is to assume that this is actual valid digital signal at all. Most likely there is a lot of noise or the signals float at a voltage near the threshold between logic 0 and logic 1. You need to take a look at the signals in analog domain with an oscilloscope.

Comment: You need to use an oscilloscope to diagnose this, not a logic analyzer.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I will get an oscilloscope and analyze what is going on.